# How should be my mysql table structure?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

**This is what I want:**

Users will send one or two values in my website and I will store them in two variables `$genres1` and `$genres2`.

Like: If user sends, Action, then my code will show all movies with Action genres. If user sends Action+Crime, then my table will fetch all movies with Action+Crime.

Got it?

My current table structure is one to many relationship, like this

```
tmdb_id    movie_title
-----------------------------
1               Iron man
2               Logan
3               Batman
4               The hangover

tmdb_id      genres
-----------------------------
1            Action
1            Crime
2            Drama
2            Action
3            Crime
3            Action
4            Comedy
4            Drama
```

But the problem here is, I can't achieve what I explained above with this.

2nd option: I make a single table like this:

```
movie_tile  genres1    genres2    genres3    genres4         
----------------------------------------------------
Logan       Action     Crime      Drama      Null         
Iron man    Action     Crime      Null       Null
```

And I can do what, I want with this single line:

```
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE (genres1='$genres1' or genres2='$genres1' orgenres1='$genres3' or genres3='$genres1')
```

Any other option?

Comment: How a bot `join`?

Comment: How join can fix my problem @Jens sir? I am trying this from 5 days, I don't know :/

Comment: It is not pretty clear what you warn. Why Loagan --> Action and crime? As i con see in your example Logan has ID2 and Genres with ID2 = Drama and Action?

Comment: It is just for example @Jens

Comment: But if you need help, you must present an example, that fits to your requirement

Comment: So please Show us your structure and the expected result

Comment: I explained everything above sir, what part you did not understand?

Comment: What is the result you expect?

Comment: If user selects just `Action`, then all movies whose genres is `Action` will echo. If user selects Action+ Crime, then all movies whose genres is `Action+Crime` will echo

Comment: do you want the result is just Iron man or Iron man, logan and batman?

Comment: In all movies (their will be like 300k movies)

Comment: Your example in this question, not all your movies samples!

Comment: I want the result to be Ironman, logan and batman @ColourDalnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the problem here is, I can't achieve what I explained above with [the first two tables]

Yes, you can. Assuming the two tables are called `movies` and `movie_genres`, you can select the movies which have both tags using:

```
SELECT movie_title FROM movies
  JOIN movie_genres genre1 USING (tmdb_id)
  JOIN movie_genres genre2 USING (tmdb_id)
WHERE genre1.genres = 'Action'
  AND genre2.genres = 'Crime'
```

[See it for yourself here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/cd844/1/0)

Comment: This is what happens: 'WHERE genre1.genres = 'Action'' Show all the movies with Action category. But removes other category from the movies. So If i use another like this ` AND genre2.genres = 'Crime'` It will show no result...Bcz first where removed all category's other than `action`

Comment: @JohnDoo Are you sure you joined against two separate instances of `movie_genres`? I recreated your tables on my local system and confirmed this query works before posting it. :)

Comment: I am using my 1st table structure as shown in the question, your table structure is different right?

Comment: @JohnDoo I'm using the exact table structure shown in the first example in your question. (With made-up names, because those weren't in your example.)

Comment: What is `genres1` here? There is nothing called `genres1` and `genres2` in my 1st table structure. It is `$genres` and `$genres2`

Comment: @JohnDoo They're table aliases to make the double JOIN work -- without that, there's no way to distinguish the two instances of `movie_genres` that get joined in. I've attached a sqlfiddle so you can see for yourself.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fpgxx3 why it gives me this error? `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.tmdb_id) JOIN genres genre2 USING (tmdb_movies.tmdb_id) WHERE genre1.genres = ' at line 9`

Comment: @JohnDoo Because you made an incorrect change to the `USING` clause. The table name doesn't belong in there.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fph37b Error `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tmdb_id' in 'from clause' in `

Answer (score 3):

use a table width genres
and use an other table connecting the movie to any genre

```
-----
movieid  title
-----
1        Logan
2        Smurf
-----

-----
genreid genre
-----
1       animated
2       blue people
-----


-----
movieid  genreid
-----
 1       1
 2       1
 2       2
-----
```

that way you won't be limited to 4 genres per movie

now I read your question better.
That's what you do, but you put left out the genre-table.

The 2nd option is bad, as you limit yourself to only 4 categories

Is this connected to PHP? I think is easiest to solve this further by a join query, sorted by movie and a loop in PHP

---

you want all movies where (by user request) the genres are both Crime And Action?

```
SELECT mg.movieid, count(1), m.title
FROM movies_genres mg
JOIN movies m ON m.movieid  mg.movieid
WHERE mg.genreid = 1 OR mg.genreid =3
group by mg.movieid, m.title
HAVING COUNT(1) = 2
```

edit: see other genres as well

```
SELECT movies.movieid,movies.title, genres.genre
FROM movies
JOIN movie_genre mg ON mg.movieid = movies.movieid
JOIN genres on genres.genreid = mg.genreid
WHERE movie.movieid IN (
    SELECT mg.movieid
    FROM movies_genres mg
    WHERE mg.genreid = 1 OR mg.genreid =3
    GROUP BY mg.movieid
    HAVING COUNT(1) = 2
)
```

forgot to mention: count = 2, means you gave 2 genreid's to find. This could also be 1, 3 or 25

Comment: I am using something very similar. But How can i filter things with this able?

Comment: Yeah, connected to PHP

Comment: See my code here, how to filter data in this code? https://pastebin.com/sDp0ZZ2D

And i am using 1st table structure

Comment: This is what happens here: 

When I use this `WHERE mg.genreid = 1` alone, it echo all the movies with genres id 1...Fair enough right? But it removes other genres of the same movie. 

For example: If Logan have 2 genres `Action`+`Drama`, And user selects, Action. Then it will remove Drama genres from Logan and echo the result

Comment: my first thought would be to use the query above as a subquery, only selecting the movieid.  Have limited time at the moment. might add it later to the query

Comment: I do not understand bro , i am really sorry. See this code, can you merge your code with this and answer? https://pastebin.com/sDp0ZZ2D

Comment: Oh thanks, but why I need change my table structure like this one? Why can't my example first table structure work? It is the same thing, i guess?

Comment: it;s indeed almost the same. Though I think one should not have the actual value as key in other tables: what is "drama" needs te be changed to "dramatic", or if you want to translate into some other language. Apart from that an index on a numeric seems easier to me

Comment: what is `mg` here?

Comment: i used mg as an alias to movies_genres so I did not need to type that much

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct a.tmdb_id, a.movie_tittle
from movie_tittle a inner join genre_tittle b
on a.tmdb_id = b.tmdb_id
where b.genres in ('Action', 'Crime')
```

Based on your comment, try this :

```
SELECT 
    a.tmdb_id, a.movie_tittle
FROM
    movie_tittle a inner join genre_tittle b
ON
    a.tmdb_id = b.tmdb_id
WHERE
    b.genres in ('Action', 'Crime')
GROUP BY 
    a.tmdb_id, a.movie_tittle
HAVING 
    count(a.tmdb_id) = 2
```

tmdb_id and genres in table genre_tittle should not duplicated. Make it as primary key.

Comment: That ends up selecting all movies which have a genre of either "Action" **or** "Crime", not only movies that have both.

Comment: Oh, weird. That is not _at all_ what I thought they meant by "+"… chalk one up for unclear questions :/

Comment: me too, I thought it's an "AND" logic, but it is like an "OR"

Comment: It is AND logic, if 2 category is selected

Comment: @JohnDoo : You want "AND" or "OR"? If it is an "AND", the result should be just *Iron man*

Comment: If someone selects `Action` then Ironman, Batman, Logan. If someone selects `Action` + `Drama` then just logan

Comment: it is just an alias actually, you can change it with any other words ;)

Answer (score 1):

try something like this :

```
tableA
Movie_ID    Movie_title
1               Iron man
2               Logan
3               Batman
4               The hangover

tableB
Genre_ID    Genre_title
1           Action
2           Crime
3           Drama
4           Comedy


tableC
ID  Movie_ID    Genre_ID
1   1          1
2   1          2
3   2          2
4   2          3
```

query :

```
Select A.Movie_title,B.Genre_title
from tableC C
inner join tableA A on A.Movie_ID = C.Movie_ID
inner join tableB B on B.Genre_ID = C.Genre_ID
where
C.Genre_ID in (IFNULL(val1,0),IFNULL(val2,0))
```

Comment: I need to change my table structure? I cannot do this with my current table structure?

Comment: Your structure is not normalized mate. You need to make design changes if you want it to last long in production in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

you should make a relational table to solve you issues like so

movie table

```
 movie_id    movie_name       genre_id
    1        alien              2
    2        logan              1
    3        ps i love you      4
    4        click              3
```

then you will need a genre table

genre table

```
  genre_id    genre_type
      1           action
      2           sci fi
      3           comedy
      4           romance
```

then your select would link the to tables

```
     function get_movies_by_genre($genre_id) {

      global $MySQLiConnect;

      $query = '
               SELECT *  
               FROM movies m
               INNER JOIN genre g ON (g.genre_id = m.genre_id) 
               WHERE g.genre_id = ? 
               ';

               $stmt = $DBConnect->stmt_init();
           if ($stmt->prepare($query)) {
               $stmt->bind_param("i", $genre_id);
               $stmt->execute();
               $result = $stmt->get_result();
               $rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
               $stmt->close();
           }

         return $rows;
     }
```

or

```
function get_movies_by_genre($genre_id) {

  global $MySQLiConnect;

  $query = '
           SELECT *  
           FROM movies m
           INNER JOIN genre g ON (g.genre_id = m.genre_id) 
           WHERE g.genre_name = ? 
           ';

           $stmt = $DBConnect->stmt_init();
       if ($stmt->prepare($query)) {
           $stmt->bind_param("i", $genre_id);
           $stmt->execute();
           $result = $stmt->get_result();
           $rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
           $stmt->close();
       }

     return $rows;
 }
```

This is the base function to get you all information from the movie table depending on which genre id you send to it.

as for multiple ids you can then run the function through a foreach loop for as many genre_ids as you need and then display them as you need.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Instead of getting them by genres_id, what is the problem, if i get them by genres_name???

Comment: there isnt an issue you would just change the query a bit  check my edit

Comment: Oh, But i don't know how to fit this code inside this code https://pastebin.com/sDp0ZZ2D

Can you help me with this also? **please**

Comment: The link just shows your select function, first you will need to made the tables and put your data in. Then the above function should just copy and paste in (if you keep the ids the same) or just edit the ids and amend in the function